# How do I calculate the average by using the get method for class objects?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to get the average years of service for the employees. When I typed the code below and run the app, it crashes. I don't know what to do, so I just commented out for now. Also to note, I want the average to be in two decimal places using the String format method only. Here is what the code that causes the crash look like:

```
try
    {
        //Create an URL object that read urlfile
        URL file_url = new URL(urlfile);

        //try to open the file from the web
        Scanner fsc = new Scanner(file_url.openStream());

        //Read the data value from the file into each Employee object
        nm = fsc.nextLine();
        e1.setName(nm);

        id = fsc.nextLine();
        e1.setId(id);

        s = fsc.nextDouble();
        fsc.nextLine();
        e1.setSalary(s);

        of = fsc.nextLine();
        e1.setOffice(of);

        ex = fsc.nextLine();
        e1.setExtension(ex);

        y = fsc.nextInt();
        fsc.nextLine();
        e1.setYearsOfServ(y);

        nm = fsc.nextLine();
        e2.setName(nm);

        id = fsc.nextLine();
        e2.setId(id);

        s = fsc.nextDouble();
        fsc.nextLine();
        e2.setSalary(s);

        of = fsc.nextLine();
        e1.setOffice(of);

        ex = fsc.nextLine();
        e2.setExtension(ex);

        y = fsc.nextInt();
        fsc.nextLine();
        e2.setYearsOfServ(y);

        nm = fsc.nextLine();
        e3.setName(nm);

        id = fsc.nextLine();
        e3.setId(id);

        s = fsc.nextDouble();
        fsc.nextLine();
        e3.setSalary(s);

        of = fsc.nextLine();
        e1.setOffice(of);

        ex = fsc.nextLine();
        e3.setExtension(ex);

        y = fsc.nextInt();
        fsc.nextLine();
        e3.setYearsOfServ(y);

        //Display all data for each employee (up to three)
        tv.setText("Employee 1:\n" + e1.getName() + "\n" + e1.getId() + "\n" + 
                e1.getSalary() + "\n" + e1.getOffice() + "\n" + e1.getExtension() + "\n" +
                e1.getYearsOfServ() + "\n" + "\n");

        tv.append("Employee 2:\n" + e2.getName() + "\n" + e2.getId() + "\n"  + 
                e2.getSalary() + "\n" + e2.getOffice() + "\n" + e2.getExtension() +
                "\n" + e2.getYearsOfServ() + "\n" + "\n");

        tv.append("Employee 3:\n" + e3.getName() + "\n" + e3.getId() + "\n"  + 
                e3.getSalary() + "\n" + e3.getOffice() + "\n" + e3.getExtension() +
                "\n" + e3.getYearsOfServ() + "\n" + "\n");

        tv.append("The average years of service:\n " + 
                ((e1.getYearsOfServ() + e2.getYearsOfServ() + e3.getYearsOfServ()) / 3.0) + "\n");

        fsc.close();

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        tv.setText("Error: Invalid URL Address or File Does Not Exist");
    }
```

Comment: what's the error/exception you seeing? What type if e1/e2/e3?

Comment: e1, e2, and e3 are class object that refers to class Employee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression:

```
(e1.getYearsOfServ() + e2.getYearsOfServ() + e3.getYearsOfServ()) / 3
```

is an integer division; therefore the result is an `int`.

And `String.format()` rightly complains that it cannot use `"%.2f"` to format an int, hence the error.

You want a double here, therefore you need at least one operand of the division to be a double:

```
(e1.getYearsOfServ() + e2.getYearsOfServ() + e3.getYearsOfServ()) / 3.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. However, I still want the average to be in two decimal places (say, 4.5 for example).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Well, I want to the answer to be in two decimal places. When the app runs that line of code that you typed in your response to my question, the output showed 4.6666666667. I want that output to be just 4.6. How would I do that?